# Extension of convex function to boundary

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be an (open) convex set and suppose $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a convex function. We can extend $f$ to the boundary as follows: For $x\in\partial C$, define
$$\tag{1}
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} \lim_{x'\rightarrow x}
f(x') & \text{if the limit exists}\\ +\infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.
$$
So we have an extend real-valued function $f:\overline{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$. This extension is not necessarily continuous even if $f$ is bounded, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451632/extension-of-bounded-convex-function-to-boundary).

However, my question is the following: Is this extension necessarily convex?

The function in (1) is defined by extending the function continuously if the limit exists.  If the extended function were *not* convex, then there would exist points $x,y\in\partial C$ on the boundary and $t\in(0,1)$ such that 
$$
f(tx+(1-t)y)>tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)
$$
This would necessarily mean that $f(x),f(y)<\infty$ but $f(tx+(1-t)y)=\infty$, but I don't think this can ever happen.

I believe that this extended function must indeed be convex, but I cannot prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Assume that $C$ **is not open**, but convex in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Define $$ C :=C_1\cup C_2,\ C_1:=\{ (x,y)| y>0 \} ,\ C_2:=
  \{ (x,0) |x<0 \} $$

Define $f|C_1=0$ and $f|C_2=1$.

Clearly $f((x,0))=0$ for all $x>0$ so that $f|\{ y=0\}$ is not convex.

(2) Assume that $C$ is open

Partial result : The case where $C$ is one-dimension is trivial.
Assume that $C$ is **two-dimensional**.

To show that extension of $f$ is convex, the following example is
considered. So it will be proved that the case arising in OP can not
happen.

Assume that $C=\{ (x,y)| y>0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $$
(x_{n},\frac{1}{n})\rightarrow (0,0),\ a_n:=(x_{2n},\frac{1}{2n} ),\
\lim_n\ f(a_n)=a,$$ $$ b_n:= (x_{2n+1},\frac{1}{2n+1}),\ \lim_n\ f
(b_n)=b <a
$$ and $f(\pm
1,0)$ is finite.

**Step 1** : WLOG $$ a_k\in {\rm conv}\ \{ (-1,\epsilon_1),\ (-1,\epsilon_2),\
b_l,\ b_m\}$$ for some $k,\ l,\ m$ where $\epsilon_i>0$ are small.

Consider $p\in [(-1,\epsilon_1)b_m]$ s.t. $a_k\in [pb_l]$

Here indexing is not important. And $[xy]$ is a **line segment** between
$x$ and $y$. Consider four points whose convex hull is **2-dimensional
4-gon** and contains $a_k$. Consider a ray starting point at $b_l$
passing through $a_k$. Hence the ray meets a side of the 4-gon. So
$[(-1,\epsilon_1) b_m]$ is denoted as the side and $p$ is the
intersection point between ray and the side.

**Step 2** : Let $$
s=d(a_k,b_l),\ t=d(a_k,p),\ u=d((-1,\epsilon_1),p),\ v= d(p,
b_m)$$

So $$ f(p) \geq \frac{(t+s)f(a_k)-tf(b_l) }{s} $$ and $$
\frac{vf(-1,\epsilon_1)+u f(b_m)  }{u+v} \geq f(p)
$$

That is $$ f(-1,\epsilon_1) \geq   \frac{1}{v} \{ (u+v)\frac{t}{s}
[f(a_k)-f(b_l)]  + v f(a_k) +u [f(a_k)-f(b_m) ] \}
$$

If $k,\ l,\ m$ is large, it can be assumed that $s,\
d(b_l,b_m)<\delta$. If $ t=Cs$, then $$ \bigg(\frac{1}{v} (u+v)\frac{t}{s}
+\frac{u}{v} \bigg)[f(a_k)-f(b_l)] \approx \frac{u+v}{C\delta+2\delta} C (a-b) +\frac{u}{C\delta+2\delta} (a-b)
$$

So $f(-1,0)=\infty $ and it is a contradiction.

**[Add]** I just suggests the some case However it rule out other cases

If $f(0,0)=\infty$, there are sequences :

1) $a_n\rightarrow (0,0)$ s.t.
$f(a_n)\rightarrow \infty$

2) $a_n,\ b_n\rightarrow (0,0)$ and $f(a_n),\ f(b_n)
\rightarrow a,\ b,\ a>b $

3) $a_n \rightarrow (0,0)$ and $f(a_n)\rightarrow -\infty$

In the first case, if $a_n=(x_n,y_n)$, then $\max\ \{ f(-1,y_n),
f(1,y_n) \} =\infty$

In the second case, if $b_n=(x_n,y_n)$, then we can assume that
$$y_n>y_{n+1}$$

Then it goes down strictly. And define $$ R_n^\pm :={\rm conv}\ \{
(x_n,y_n), ( x_{n+1},y_{n+1} ), (\pm 1,y_n),(\pm 1,y_{n+1}) \} $$

Each $R_{n}^\pm$ is a closed 2-dimensional 4-gon. In further
$$\bigcup_n\ R_n^+ \cup \bigcup_n\ R_n^-$$ contains ${\rm conv}\ \{
(-1,y_1),(1,y_1),(-1,\epsilon ),(1,\epsilon )\}$ for any $\epsilon
>0$

By reindexing, we can assume that $a_n$ is in $R_n^-$. If $a_n$ is
in the interior of $R_n^-$, then the above argument holds

If $a_n\in [b_n (-1,y_n)]$, then note that $$\frac{ f(-1,y_n) |a_n-b_n| + f(b_n) |(-1,y_n)-a_n| }{|-1-x_n|} \geq
f(a_n)  $$

So if $ \lim_n\ f(-1,y_n) =C$ is finite, then $C\cdot \lim_n\
|a_n-b_n| + b \geq a $. Hence we have a contradiction.

If $a_n \in [b_nb_{n+1}]$, then note that $\max\ \{ f(b_n),f(b_{n+1}) \} <\frac{a+b}{2}< f(a_n)$ for
sufficiently large $n$. It contradicts to convexity of $f$.

In third case, assume that $a_n=(x_n,y_n),\ f(a_n) <-n$ Then
$f(-1,y_n)\rightarrow a$ Then $$ \frac{ f(-1- \epsilon,y_n)\cdot |-1-x_n| +
f(a_n)\cdot \epsilon }{|-1-x_n|+\epsilon } \geq f(-1,y_n) $$

If $ \epsilon = \frac{-1}{f(a_n)}$, then we have $a-1\geq a$ by
limiting. So it is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't get your first example.   It looks like you are trying to show what can go wrong if $C$ is not open.  But, convex functions must be defined over convex sets, and your set $C$ is not convex.

Comment: @ Michael The $C$ in the first example is indeed convex. It is the open upper half plane with the positive $x$ axis added in.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer : I add more explanation

Comment: I'm trying to understand your proof, and I think it boils down to this: We can suppose that $C$ is the open upper-half plane. Suppose the continuous limits exist at $(\pm1,0)$, but not at $(0,0)$. Then find two different sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ both converging to $(0,0)$ such that $f(a_n)\rightarrow a$ and $f(b_n)\rightarrow b$ with $b<a$. Then you show that $f(-1,0)=\infty$ (which I'm still trying to understand), which is a contradiction.

Comment: This leads to a few questions: How can we assume that such sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ exist? And why can they have the form that you have given them, as subsequences of some sequence of the form $(x_n,\frac{1}{n})$?

Comment: I add explanation about other cases.

Comment: @HKLee Thanks for the clarification, but I still have a few more questions. What do you means by "If $a_n\in [b_n (-1,y_n)]$, then $f(-1,y_n)$ is large" and "If $a_n \in [b_nb_{n+1}]$, then it is a contradiction"?

Comment: I add more explanation.

Comment: Great! I understand now. Thanks.