# Convergence of subgradients

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a compact, convex subset of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $g:\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{R}\cup\infty$ an extended valued, proper, lower semicontinuous, convex function. Also, assume that $C\subset dom(\partial g)$, where $\partial g$ is the convex subdifferential of $g$ and $dom(\partial g) = \{x\in\mathcal{H}: \partial g (x)\neq\emptyset\}$.

I am interested in the following claim:

Given a convergent sequence $x_n\in C$ with $x_n\to x\in C$ and a sequence of subgradients $b_n \in \partial g(x_n)$, we have $\exists b\in \partial g(x)$ such that $b_n\to b$.

Even a weaker version, in which it is only true that $\exists b\in \partial g(x)$ such that $\exists b_{n_k}$ with $b_{n_k}\to b$ for a subsequence, would be interesting as well.

A related question I am interested in as well is the following: is there a name for this type of 'continuity' for a correspondence/multi-valued function $G$,

$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0 \mbox{ such that } \|x-y\|<\delta\implies \exists u\in G(x), v\in G(y): \|u-v\|<\varepsilon$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without boundedness of $b_n$ this will not work.

Here is an example:
Take $H$ at least two-dimensional, $x\in H$, $y\in H$ with $y\ne0$, $(x,y)=0$. Define $g=I_{\{y\}^\perp}$, which is the indicator function of the convex set $\{y\}^\perp$:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } (x,y)=0\\
+\infty & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}
$$

Define $x_n:=x$, $b_n:=n\cdot y_n$.

If the sequence $(b_n)$ has a weakly converging subsequence, then the weak limit is a subgradient again.

Comment: Is $g(t) = \infty$ for $t \bot y$? How is $g$ convex?

Comment: $g(t)= 0$ for $t\perp y$ and $g(t) = \infty$ otherwise if I understand correctly.

Comment: Is $\bot$ the orthogonal complement? If so, I don't see how $g$ is convex.

Comment: I think so yes?

Comment: @copper.hat see edit

Comment: Sorry, lack of caffeine...

Comment: @daw perhaps you could take a look at my original question here, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795331/showing-that-the-hausdorff-distance-from-the-subdifferential-to-0-is-bounded    the sequence $b_n$ i originally wanted to consider is unbounded by assumption.

Comment: @daw why do we know that the weak limit is a subgradient?