# Are closed convex functions continuous?

Tags: convex-analysis

A function is called closed if its epigraph is closed -- see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_convex_function) for a little more detail. Suppose $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex set and $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a closed convex function. Does it follow that $f$ is continuous on $D$?

If $D$ is an interval, the answer is yes, and this is Proposition 1.3.12 in the textbook *Convex Optimization Theory* by Bertsekas. The fact that the proposition is stated for an interval suggests that the answer to my question might be negative, but I'm having trouble thinking of a counterexample.

Comment: It is also interesting that closed convex functions on polytopes (i.e., $f$ is convex and $D$ is a polytope) are continuous, see [this](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr018-ConvFnsConvPolytopes.pdf) paper.

Comment: More examples can be found in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451632

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convex function is closed if and only if it is lower semi-continuous, but a closed convex function is not neccesarily continuous. Here is a celebrated example:
$$D=\{(x,y) \mid y\geq x^2\}$$
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2}{y} & \text{if } y\geq x^2 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \text{ and } y=0. \end{cases} $$
This function is discontinuous in $(0,0)$ since you could walk over the curve $y=x^2$ or over $y=2x^2$ and end up with different function values. However, it is lower-semicontinuous and convex (see next paragraph), and hence closed.

Convexity for $y>0$ is trivial (quadratic over linear is known to be convex). For any $(x_1,y_1) \in D$ with $y_1=0$ (and hence $x_1=0$) and for any $(x_2,y_2) \in D$ with $y_2>0$ and for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we have:
$$\lambda f(x_1,y_1) + (1-\lambda)f(x_2,y_2) = \frac{(1-\lambda)x_2^2}{y_2}$$
$$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2,\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) = \frac{((1-\lambda) x_2)^2}{(1-\lambda)y_2} = \frac{(1-\lambda) x_2^2}{y_2}$$
from which convexity follows.

Comment: Thanks. I'm having some trouble seeing why this is lower semicontinuous. It seems like at the origin, we can take $(x_n, y_n) = (1/n,10/n^2) \rightarrow (0,0)$ with  $f(x_n, y_n) = 1/10$, so $\lim \inf_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} f(x_n,y_n) \leq 1/10$; but for lower semicontinuity, the latter quantity should be above $f(0,0)=1$.

Comment: @M.S. you are right, I have changed the function value to 0.

Comment: This example can be found in Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*...

Comment: @max_zorn I see it on Page 83 but the domain is different. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: You are right - does Rockafellar's example do it as well or only your example?

Comment: @max_zorn his example works too! It is convex and lower-semicontinuous, and hence, convex.